# range of AS numbers which are given out by RIRs

Tags: bgp

I need to have a range of AS numbers which are allocated by RIRs/NIRs. I guess it is every number from 0 to 2^32 except those below:

```
0                        - reserved ASN
23456                    - AS_TRANS
64496 - 64511            - reserved for documentation
64512 - 65534            - private ASN
65535                    - reserved ASN
65536 - 65551            - reserved for documentation
4200000000 - 4294967294  - private ASN
4294967295               - reserved ASN
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find all AS tracking resources at IANA, which is the central authority on it as it distributes AS numbers to RIRs.

List of all assigned blocks of AS numbers:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/as-numbers/as-numbers.xhtml
(you have both the 16-bit and the 32-bit registries)

List of all special purpose ones:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-as-numbers-special-registry/iana-as-numbers-special-registry.xhtml
which is the following list, close but not equal to yours:

```
 AS Number      Reason for Reservation  Reference
 0              Reserved by [RFC7607]   [RFC7607]
 112            Used by the AS112 project to sink misdirected DNS queries; see [RFC7534]    [RFC7534]
 23456          AS_TRANS; reserved by [RFC6793]     [RFC6793]
 64496-64511    For documentation and sample code; reserved by [RFC5398]    [RFC5398]
 64512-65534    For private use; reserved by [RFC6996]  [RFC6996]
 65535          Reserved by [RFC7300]   [RFC7300]
 65536-65551    For documentation and sample code; reserved by [RFC5398]    [RFC5398]
 4200000000-4294967294  For private use; reserved by [RFC6996]  [RFC6996]
 4294967295     Reserved by [RFC7300]   [RFC7300]
```